# rotate the robot using cmd_vel

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I tried to rotate the pioneer robot using cmd_vel / geometry/Twist with angular.z value.
the robot turns but not nice, sometimes slow, then fast :(
I searched the internet to solve that task, but it hasn't helped.
can anyone help me to rotate the robot lets say 30degree. a c++ code snippet would be awesome, but I'm thankful for any help...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30213/rotate-the-robot-using-cmd_vel/) by [berni_ka](https://answers.ros.org/users/2030/berni_ka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally publishing on cmd_vel with an angular.z value should be fine. If it it doesn't behave, I would actually blame the node that provides cmd_vel. Did you try with higher rotational values? Does it get more stable then? Maybe there is a minimal velocity on your motors and the driver runs a controller to reach lower rotational values as good as possible.

If you want to move the robot to a specific coordinate in odometry, e.g. 30 degrees rotated from the current position, check out [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20base%20controller%20with%20odometry%20and%20transform%20information) tutorial.

For path planning and collision avoidance, check out [move_base](http://ros.org/wiki/move_base).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1